# Is it possible to sort the numpy array in descending order using numpy.sort(), If possible then how?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am just wondering how to sort a NumPy array in descending order using NumPy sort() function efficiently. I checked the NumPy official documentation and StackOverflow question but I couldn`t able to find how to sort a NumPy array in descending order using the NumPy sort().

```
For instance:

import numpy as np
arr=np.array([1,5,8,4,5])
arr.sort()
print(arr)

Output:

[1,4,5,5,8]
```

I want to sort it by descending order, I understand after sorting the array in ascending order, I can reverse it like below.

```
arr.sort()[::-1]
```

But it creates a new array, Is it possible to sort descending without approaching this method?

Comment: basically you want to reverse the array first and then sort `arr[::-1].sort()`

Comment: Flipping with `[::-1]` creates a view, not a copy.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`-np.sort(-arr)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([1,5,8,4,5])
print(-np.sort(-arr))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[8 5 5 4 1]
```